# Mongodb atlas search: apply multiple language analyzers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

There is a collection namely - categories, which has following schema

```
{
    name: String,
    language: { $type: String, default: "de"}
    translation:[
      {
          language: { $type: String, enum: ["en","fr"]}, 
          name:String
      }
    ]
}
```

It has language specific data, other than name too like - description and more. I want to create atlas search index on name field for all three languages. I have tried creating atlas search index with **'name'** and **'translation.name'**, but it did not work for translation.name. Here is the atlas search index:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.german",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "translation.name": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.french",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
}
```

Problem here is, if I specify language analyzer for translation.name as german, I can not apply the same for english. How multiple language analyzers can be used for a single field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the index definition documentation for atlas search, I found the answer to my query i.e. applying multiple language anlayzers for a single field. Here is the link to the documentation -

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/index-definitions/

And this is what I have modified my mappings to:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.german",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "translation": {
        "type": "document",
        "fields": {
          "name": {
            "multi": {
              "english": {                //english is the name that I have given to this analyzer
                "analyzer": "lucene.english",
                "type": "string"
              },
              "french": {                //french is the name that I have given to this analyzer
                "analyzer": "lucene.french",
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```